# Need to write a Google Analytics regex pattern for newsletter signup tracking

Tags: regex, google-analytics, newsletter

This is slightly beyond my ken.

I have a newsletter signup confirmation URL formed like:
http://godoymedical.net/?wysija-page=1&controller=confirm&wysija-key=7b246d4fc4c91968b0529237169787df&action=subscribe&wysijap=subscriptions&wysiconf=YToyOntpOjA7czoxOiI0IjtpOjE7czoxOiIzIjt9

I need to track it with RegEx in Google Analytics. The important parts are clearly:

wysija-page=1
controller=confirm
action=subscribe

When that stuff appears in an URL, I need to record it as a signup. Yeah, way over my head. Anyone here done this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture everything no matter what the string might be after `=` then you could use:

```
(wysija-page=\d+)(?:.*)(controller=\w+)(?:.*)(action=\w+)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/tP1fG3

If you specifically only want page=1 controller=confirm, etc.

```
(wysija-page=1)(?:&.*)(controller=confirm)(?:.*)(action=subscribe)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/hI3pO2

Comment: Will test this when I get back to the office :)

Comment: I'll have to blog this and credit you for the answer. The second option was nails: "This Goal would have a 2.63% conversion rate based on your data from the past 7 days."